# NSURLRequest using HTTPS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm converting a bunch of ASI connection requests with the NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest classes from apple.

one of the issues is that the post request has to use https.. but I'm not sure if this is possible with NSURLRequest, this is currently how my code looks.

```
NSData *postBodyData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [postBodyString UTF8String] length:[postBodyString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:yourURL]; 
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postBodyData];
```

My question is, will this work over https, do I have to do anything extra to make sure I am complying with https security standards.. or something else that I'm unaware of.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the server has an SSL certificate that isn't self-signed, you don't need to anything more than set the url to `https`. Some other considerations only need to be made if you're doing HTTP authentication.

Comment: cheers DOG! <-- not sure if you will get the refrence but thanks very much for clearing that up for me :).

Comment: yo dawg I herd you like https so I put a http in your https so you can http while you https